# Событие внутри jquery.each

Tags: jquery

```
$(".cartProduct").each(function() {
    var priceOfProduct = $(this).children(".priceOfProduct").text();
    var numberOfProductCart=1;
    $(this).children(".sumPriceOfProduct").text(numberOfProductCart*priceOfProduct);
    $(this).find('.shest').keyup(function() {
        numberOfProductCart = $(this).val();
        $(".sumPriceOfProduct").text(numberOfProductCart*priceOfProduct);
    });
});
```

Класс `sumPriceOfProduct` является дочерним от `cartProduct`, которых бесконечное количество штук. Нужно чтобы `sumPriceOfProduct` изменялся в каждом `cartProduct` независимо, думал тут поможет `this`, но при `this` он обращается к анонимной функции при событии `keyup`,а нужно чтобы к `cartProduct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback, который передается в `each` вызывается с 2 параметрами — ключ(номер) и значение. Можете использовать их или сохранить `this` в какую либо переменную — например `self`

```
 $(".cartProduct").each(function(i, el) { 
    var self = this;
    var priceOfProduct = $(el).children(".priceOfProduct").text();
    var numberOfProductCart=1;
    $(el).children(".sumPriceOfProduct").text(numberOfProductCart*priceOfProduct);
    $(el).find('.shest').keyup(function() {
        numberOfProductCart = $(this).val();
        $(el).children(".sumPriceOfProduct").text(numberOfProductCart*priceOfProduct);
    });
});
```

Comment: Теперь выдает ноль,а должен выдавать количество товаров умноженное на его цену ,раньше выводилось и то и то,просто мне нужно событие ,которое их умножит .

Comment: Да и вот в том варианте ,который я выложил все происходит верно,но для всех sumPriceOfProduct сразу.

Comment: @QopOp Поправил